# search and read value of a number from innerHTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

i am fetching the innerHTML of table rows.

The innerHTML of first row is like (All other rows start in a similar way,only the number in place of 131 will be different)

```
  <td><input id="TPP_cb_0" type="checkbox" onclick="sphinx.dbox.select(event, {ID:   '131'});" /></td>
   <td>
    ....more data and tds
   </td>
```

I want to know how can i search and read what is the value of the number (like it is 131 for first row)

UPDATE: The innerHTML posted is just a string that is read in some function say Fn() .I need to read the values of numbers inside Fn.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you please clarify where you want to check the ID, and what information you have. Are you just dealing with a string of HTML that you are reading, or do you mean inside the onclick function (`sphinx.dbox.select`) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this :

```
var num = +yourHTML.match(/\{ID:\s*'(\d+)'\}/)[1];
```

The exact regex might depend on what you expect in your rows.

Comment: Did I misunderstood his question ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir I'm not totally sure either. I hope one of our answers will be useful...

Comment: @RoyiNamir No idea - I've left a comment asking the OP to clarify for everyone

Comment: Funny that someone tagged it as a fav without knowing what the question was.

Comment: @RoyiNamir It's my way of bookmarking questions I want to come back and see the following day.

Comment: @dystroy Great Idea. Adopting that idea. ( for such questions) tnx for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to read it at the function level ?

If you do  - then

```
 function   sphinx.dbox.select(e,o)
    {
     alert(o.ID) ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner solution could be:

```
<input id="TPP_cb_0" myid="131" type="checkbox" onclick="sphinx.dbox.select(event);" />
```

in your onclick function you can get myid by:

```
event.srcElement.getAttribute("myid")
```

outside the function:

```
document.getElementById("TPP_cb_0").getAttribute("myid")
```